# Escaping newlines in Jade scripts

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have a Jade template with lines like these:

```
html
    head
        title Person Details
        script
            var Person = function () {
                this.name = "#{person.name}",
                this.contactInfo = "#{person.contactInfo}"
            }
...
```

When I render this template I pass it a `person` object.

The problem is that some of the fields I pass to the template (such as `person.contactInfo` above) may have newline characters, and the rendering process outputs something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Person Details</title>
        <script>
            var Person = function () {
                this.name = "Joe Schmoe",
                this.contactInfo = "Phone: 555-1234.
Address: 555 Main St."
            }
...
```

...which throws an Unexpected Token error.

Can I escape newline characters to avoid this problem? Or must I escape them before sending the data to the render engine?

Comment: What if you write it like this - `"!{person.contactInfo}"` - instead?

Comment: Using the bang makes no difference in this case, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've heard, rendering data into scripts is bad practice. I would imagine this is the issue looking at what you're experiencing. A potentially better option would be to use `#{JSON.stringify(person)}` and then parse that using `JSON.parse()` on the client side. This way you needn't worry what characters are in your `person` object as the `JSON` object is taking care of that for you.

```
html
    head
        title Person Details
    body
        input(type="hidden", name="person", value="#{JSON.stringify(person)}")
        script
           var Person = function () {
               var _person = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="person"]').value;
                   _person = JSON.parse(_person);

           for (var key in _person) {
                 this[key] = _person[key];
              };
           };
```

...

Semantically I would put it in an input tag, which is odd really, who knows. Ideally I think you should do an XMLHttpRequest when the page loads and use JSON as the `content-type`, that way you aren't doing anything funky.