# Passing objects from NodeJS to client and then into KnockoutJS viewmodel

Tags: javascript, node.js, knockout.js, requirejs

So thanks to SO I can pass an object from node to the client, but then getting it into a knockout view model is a bit awkward. These are the steps I have so far (I've included links to the relevant lines as they appear in my github project. Thought the context might help.):

1. Apply `JSON.stringify` and pass to the jade file

   ```
   recipeJSON: JSON.stringify(recipe);
   ```
2. Wrap this in a [function in a header script](https://github.com/SebastianCarroll/RecipeManager/blob/e44731d93577738c980c86ef53ec78f6f4fcfa47/public/javascripts/recipe-edit.js#L15) that just parses the JSON and returns the result

   ```
       script        
           function getRecipeObject() {
               var r = '!{recipeJSON}';
               return JSON.parse(r);
           }
   ```
3. Call this function and pass the result to a [view model constructor](https://github.com/SebastianCarroll/RecipeManager/blob/master/views/recipe_edit.jade#L7-L11)

   ```
   self.recipe = ko.observable(new Recipe(getRecipeObject()));
   ```

This works but is there a better way?

**Question clarification (Edit):** I feel step 2 shouldn't be necessary. Is there a way to directly pass the JSON from node to the Recipe() constructor, without the `getRecipeObject()` acting as an intermediate step? I tried passing `recipeJSON` in directly like so

```
self.recipe = ko.observable(JSON.parse('!{recipeJSON}'));
```

That doesn't work I think because its not a jade template and has no access to the variable.

Comment: You can use the automapper Knockout plugin http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, was your comment with reference to improving the `ko.observable(JSON.parse('!{recipeJSON}'));` line? If so, I'm not sure that was the improvement I was originally after but I'll look into it. Could you check my clarification to see if my assumptions are correct?

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034325/escaping-newlines-in-jade-scripts) rendering data into scripts is bad practice and I should instead make an XHR call on page load instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

I just saw you linked a github repo!  So you're already familiar with most of this...you even have an endpoint set up at `/recipe/:id/view`, so now I'm really confused...what isn't working out for you?  Just the last step of deserialization using `ko.utils.*`?

Sorry about all the exposition -- I thought this was way more rudimentary than it actually was; I hope no offense taken there!

---

You really don't want to return a script to execute -- instead, treat this as a DTO: an object that just stores data (no behaviors).  An example would be:

```
{
   recipeID: 12,
   reviewIDs: [42, 12, 55, 31],
   rating: 4.2
   recipeName: "A super tasty pie!"
}
```

This object (representation) is a projection -- a simplified version of the full data stored in the database.

The next step is to create an endpoint to access that data on the server.  Let's assume you're using Express:

```
var app = express();
app.get('/recipes/:recipeID', function(req, res) {
     var recipeID = req.params.recipeID;

     // It would be cool if this existed, huh?
     getRecipeAsync(recipeID, function(recipe) {
         res.status(200).json(recipe);
     });
});
```

If you send a GET request to your (hypothetical) application (let's say it's https://localhost:8080/recipes/12), you'll get json representing the (admittedly imaginary) recipe with ID 12.

You can accomplish getting the JSON with jQuery (or any other library that makes XHR nice and pretty)

```
var recipeID = 12;

$.ajax({
   url: "/recipes/" + recipeID,
   type: "GET"
}).then(function(recipe) {
   console.log("Hey! I got the recipe: %O", recipe);

   // Note: you might need to use ko.utils.fromJS(recipe) if the returned
   // data is JSON that ISN'T deserialized into an object
   var recipeObservable = ko.utils.fromJS(recipe);
});
```

That's about everything you need to know.  Obviously, the devil's in the details, but that's basic idea; let me know if that helps!